# Set an authentication token in a request header when using supertest with jest and express

Tags: javascript, express, jestjs, supertest

I'm trying to test the routes in my `express` app that are protected by a jwt middleware. I've tried simulating a request to get the jwt token in a `beforeAll` call:

```js
let token = "";
beforeAll((done) => {
    supertest(app)
        .get("/authentication/test")
        .end((err, response) => {
            console.log(response.body); // "fewiu3438y..." (successfully got token) 
            token = response.body.token; // Tried to update token variable with jwt token
            done();
        });
});
console.log(token); // "" (I haven't updated the token variable)
```

So when I try to run subsequent tests, I don't have a valid authentication token to use in the headers:

```js
    describe("Simple post test using auth", () => {
        test.only("should respond with a 200 status code", async () => {
            console.log({ POSTTest:token }); // "" still not set, so test will fail.
            const response = await supertest(app).post("/tests/simple").send();
            expect(response.statusCode).toBe(200);
        });
    });
```

Is there a way to update a variable, or else set all headers using a `beforeAll`? Or is there a better method I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try to use an `async` function as a `beforeAll` callback:

```
let token = '';

beforeAll(async () => {
  const response = await supertest(app).get('/authentication/test');
  token = response.body.token;
});
```

Then, use the `set` method to pass the token in the test:

```
describe('Simple post test using auth', () => {
  test.only('should respond with a 200 status code', async () => {
    const response = await supertest(app)
      .post('/tests/simple')
      .set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);

    expect(response.statusCode).toBe(200);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I am doing like this

```
    import * as request from 'supertest';

    describe('Simple post test using auth', () => {
    test.only('should respond with a 200 status code', async () => {
     const res = await request(app.getHttpServer())
      .post('/tests/simple')
      .send(payload)
      .set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);

    expect(res.statusCode).toBe(200);
  });
});
```

Also I have a suggestion that you mock your authentication request. Here is similar question for that if you are using jest
[Mock Authentication Request -Jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53406347/jest-mock-express-jwt-middleware-behavior-for-protected-routes)

Comment: Are you suggesting to turn off the security check for the token? What if I forget to protect the endpoint? When someone is writing a test like this (from outside), I assume they want to test everything.

Comment: I am suggesting to mock the request / response and not the actual endpoint
this is only for test